# How can I render html content as pdf file using phantomJs in node.JS

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, phantomjs

How can I generate a pdf file with some html content and render the file and content to the browser using phantom.js in node.js?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not use the [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) npm module which uses phantomJS?

Code example

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' } 
});
```

Comment: can I pass url like this `var html = fs.readFileSync('http://localhost:3000/product/generate-invoice', 'utf8');` to generate pdf report?

Comment: The characters are becoming cut at the end of each pdf. It's a dynamic pdf. Hot to solve it.