# TEdgeBrowser, how to set the filename for save to pdf

Tags: delphi

With the TEdgeBrowser, how can I programatically set the full path for the filename for print --> Save as PDF ?

The other question is how to select the Save as pdf printer in code?

Comment: This is a limitation of Microsoft Edge itself, it simply does not provide any option for either of those issues. You cannot choose a path or filename for the print, and only the user can choose which printer to use. So, you will have to either 1) install a 3rd party PDF Printer and print to that instead, or 2) use a different browser.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm probably eventually going to have to find a different browser. <rant>I don't think I'll ever _want_ to understand those types of design choices -- I mean I get the security aspects, but it just seems like they (Microsoft?) went out of their way to make Edge impossible to automate, or interact with in any meaningful way. </rant>

Comment: If Delphi isn't required to accomplish your goal then maybe this can help: [How can I render html content as pdf file using phantomJs in node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37223714/how-can-i-render-html-content-as-pdf-file-using-phantomjs-in-node-js/37223759)